# Saving an associative array with references as values in doctrine-mongodb

Tags: php, doctrine, php-mongodb, doctrine-mongodb

How can I map a field inside a document as associative array whose values are references to another document?

Let's say I have a document `File` which represents some file on disk. Something like this:

```
/** @Document */
class File {

    /** @Id */
    protected $id;

    /** @String */
    protected $filename;

    // Getter and setters omitted
}
```

And another document representing an image, which stores references to different sizes of an image. Something like this:

```
/** @Document */
class Image {

    /** @Id */
    protected $id;

    /** ???? */
    protected $files;

    // Getter and setters omitted
}
```

I now want to be able to store some references to files in the image document keyed by their size. For exampl:

```
$file1 = new File('/some/path/to/a/file');
$file2 = new File('/some/path/to/another/file');

$image = new Image();
$image->setFiles(array('50x50' => $file1,'100x100' => $file2));
```

The resulting MongoDB document should look something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("...."),
    "files" : {
        "50x50" : {
            "$ref" : "files",
            "$id" : ObjectId("...")
        },
        "100x100" : {
            "$ref" : "files",
            "$id" : ObjectId("...")
        }
    }
}
```

So how do I map the `files` field in the `Image` document?

Answer (score 0):

Use "set" strategy with Doctrine's ArrayCollection

```
/** @Document */
class Image {

    /** @Id */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ReferenceMany(targetDocument="File", strategy="set") 
     */

    protected $files;

    public function setFile($resolution, File $file)
    {
        $this->files[$resolution] = $file;
    }

    // Getter and setters omitted
}
```